# Python Selenium click checkbox without id and name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to set up an automation that can help me work easier. I want to log in to a device automatically and set up some initial settings. The part I am having trouble with is that I have to check a checkbox to continue, but I couldn't find a way to click on the button.
[image: link]

This is the XPath for that button:

```
//*[@id="tableHdd"]/div/div[1]/span[1]/input

broswer.find_element_by_class_name('table-cell').find_elements_by_class_name('checkbox').click()
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Please avoid snapshot rather post html in text format on your original post.

Comment: Thank you all for all the corrections. This is the first time that i used this to ask the question. I will work on my grammar and some other stuff in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `clcick()` on the *checkbox* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#tableHdd > div.table > div.table-header > span.table-cell > input.checkbox"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='tableHdd']/div[@class='table']/div[@class='table-header']/span[@class='table-cell']/input[@class='checkbox']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your solution and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing [Element Locators](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

- [`find_element_*`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) should return a single unique [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement). If the locator matches > 1 element - the first match will be returned.
- [`find_elements_*`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements) - returns the [List](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) of WebElements, you cannot invoke [`click()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) function from the list

So if there is only one checkbox at the page - you can tick it like:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("checkbox").click()
```

If there are more checkboxes and you need to tick particular that one - use slightly amended [XPath expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='tableHdd']/descendant::*/span[@class='table-cell']/input").click()
```